# sd card installation in s7582

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I am having a problem with my sd card installation. After inserting sd card in my phone, still its showing "insert sd card". Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: does this happens for all memory cards or for a particular one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another memory card try it out and see if it works.  If it does then your first memory card may be corrupt or damaged.  If the second memory card doesn't work either then it's possible there is a problem with your SD card slot on the phone.  If the problem is the SD card slot then you may need to look into a warranty replacement for the phone, if that option is available.